# Touch file with content using java

Tags: java

I have a `JSON` withe the following content

```
{
   "version": "3",
   "type": "simple",
   "count": "4"
}
```

I have the above content as a `String`. Now I'm trying to push this content to a file in `unix` OS as below

```
        String userInfo = getUserInfo(); //This gets the above json object
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        lines.add("#! /bin/bash");
        lines.add("cd /home/user");
        lines.add("touch userinfo.json");
        lines.add("echo " + userInfo + " >> userinfo.json");
```

Now when the above commands are executed it creates a new file `userinfo.json` but the content is no `json` content anymore. It looks like below

```
version: 3 type: simple count: 4
```

I think it's escaping the characters? How do I go about achieving this?

PS: This is the only way I have to create `Launch scripts` in `AWS EC2` when the `instance` is started.

Comment: Alternatively, could you use a heredoc? `lines.add("cat << EOT >> userinfo.json"); lines.add(userInfo); lines.add("EOT");`, or something like?

Comment: heredoc looks promising. I'll try that

Comment: @AndyTurner: That perfectly worked fine. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing it inline, use a heredoc, since this would not need escaping:

```
lines.add("cat << EOT >> userinfo.json"); 
lines.add(userInfo);
lines.add("EOT");
```